# how a function in python is getting called by just typing the name of function and not using brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

First of all to find "lcm" of two numbers I made a function `lcm(a, b)`. Then I thought of finding "hcf" too so I made a decorator `decor` and defined a function `hcf(a, b)` in it. And then I returned this function by just typing the name of the function and I didn't put brackets with it but it is still working. I cant understand why this function is working even though I didn't used brackets.

```
def decor(lcm_arg):        # just to practice decorators
    def hcf(a, b):
        if a > b:
            a, b = b, a
        while True:
            if b % a == 0:
                print("hcf is", a)
                break
            else:
                a, b = b % a, a
        return lcm_arg(a, b)
    return hcf              # how hcf function is working without using brackets

@decor
def lcm(a, b):
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    for x in range(b, a*b+1, b):
        if x % a == 0:
            print("lcm is", x)
            break


lcm(2, 4)
```

Output:

```
hcf is 2
lcm is 4
```

Comment: Has your question been answered, or do you need further explanation?

Comment: @timgeb - Well, I am a beginner and i dont know much about python yet. I am still trying to help me out with my doubt....but thanks a lot man for your support.....but i still cant understand that why the inner function inside the decorator runs on returning by just typing its name....and why we are not using parrntheses with it

Comment: But the inner function **does not run on returning it**! My answer lists all the function calls in order and all of them happen with parentheses. `return hcf` does **not** call `hcf`.

Comment: if `return hcf` does not call the function then how its functionality is working

Comment: and this is also not clear to me that how the inner function takes the arguments...like they seem to me the formal arguments but they work as the actual arguments taken from the function passed as an argument in the decorator

Comment: In your code, `hcf` is called when you call `lcm`, because the decorating does `lcm = decor(lcm)`.

Comment: One last question....what actually `return hcf` will do ?

Comment: Do you know what `return 1` would do? It's exactly the same, just that the function `hcf` is returned instead of the value `1`.

Comment: Okk..thanxx man...i appreciate ur help

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you understand decorators. Let's make a minimal example.

```
def my_decorator(some_function):        
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        'announces the result of some_function, returns None'
        result = some_function(*args, **kwargs)
        print('{} produced {}'.format(some_function.__name__, result))
    return new_function # NO FUNCTION CALL HERE!

@my_decorator
def my_function(a, b):
    return a + b

my_function(1, 2) # will print "my_function produced 3"
```

We have a simple function `my_function` which returns the sum of its two arguments and a decorator which will just print out the result of whatever function it decorates.

Note that

```
@my_decorator
def my_function(a, b):
    return a + b
```

is equivalent to

```
def my_function(a, b):
    return a + b

my_function = my_decorator(my_function)
```

Since `my_decorator` accepts a function as an argument (here we are giving it `my_function`) and returns a *new function* `new_function` (without calling it!), we effectively override `my_function` because we reassign the name to whatever `my_decorator` returns.

In action:

```
>>> my_function(1, 2)
my_function produced 3
```

Note that at every point in the example when a function is called, it happens with the parentheses-syntax. Here are all the function calls that happen in the first block of code I posted, in order:

1. `my_decorator(my_function)` is called and the return value is reassigned to the name `my_function`. This either happens through the `@` syntax or more explicitly in the equivalent code snippet.
2. `my_function(1, 2)` is called. At this point, `my_function` is the `new_function` that got returned by the decorator. Brain-parse it as `new_function(1, 2)`.
3. Inside the body of `new_function`, the argument we gave to `my_decorator` is called (`result = some_function(*args, **kwargs)`) which happens to be the value of `my_function` **before the reassignment that happened in step 1**.
4. `print` is called.

If you want to understand how `new_function` is holding on to `some_function` despite `my_decorator` already having returned from its call, I suggest looking into the topics *free variables* and *closures*.

Answer (score 1):

`return hcf` does not call the function because there are no parentheses, as you noticed. The `decor` function is used as a decorator which reassigns the name `lcm` to refer to the returned function. What I mean by this is that

```
@decor
def lcm(a, b):
    // ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def lcm(a, b):
    // ...

lcm = decor(lcm)
```

After this executes, `lcm` refers to the function `hcf`. So calling `lcm(2, 4)` now executes the code in `hcf`. I think the key here is to understand that at the line `lcm(2, 4)`, `lcm` and `hcf` are two names which refer to the same function.