# 'NoneType' object is not callable with decorator class

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-decorators

I'm learning about decorator classes using this resource:
   http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/decorators.html#decorator-classes

The presented class is basically this:

```
class logit(object):
    def __init__(self, logfile='out.log'):
        self.logfile = logfile

    def __call__(self, func):
        log_string = func.__name__ + " was called"
        print(log_string)
        # Open the logfile and append
        with open(self.logfile, 'a') as opened_file:
            # Now we log to the specified logfile
            opened_file.write(log_string + '\n')
        # Now, send a notification
        self.notify()

    def notify(self):
        # logit only logs, no more
        pass
```

and the call:

```
@logit()
def myfunc1():
    pass

myfunc1()
```

I get an error:

```
>>> myfunc1()
[...]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Given your invocation, make sure your `__call__` method returns a callable (maybe `return func`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logit.__call__` does return `None`, and you are doing `myfunc1 = logit()(myfunc1)` via decoration. `myfunc` is now `None`.

As far as I understand, you want to log each call of the decorated function. In this case, `__call__` must build a new function and `return` it.

Something like

```
def __call__(self, func):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        log_string = func.__name__ + " was called"
        print(log_string)
        # Open the logfile and append
        with open(self.logfile, 'a') as opened_file:
            # Now we log to the specified logfile
            opened_file.write(log_string + '\n')
        # Now, send a notification
        self.notify()

        # execute func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_func
```

Now

```
@logit()
def myfunc1():
    pass
```

does

```
myfunc1 = logit()(myfunc1)
```

i.e. it reassigns the name `myfunc1` to the new function built in `__call__`. This new function does the logging-logic and then executes the old `myfunc1` which it still holds onto under the name `func` as a closure variable.

Comment: thanks for mentioning about `new_func` and why it is needed (or not needed, depending on the use case).
for anyone interested, i tried calling `my_func()` with and without it. without `new_func`, the second call to `my_func()` didn't call the `__call__`. with it, every time `my_func()` is called, `__call__` will be called.

Comment: @user3132457 not exactly. In both scenarios, `__call__` is called exactly once. But in the second example you override `myfunc1` with the new function produced in the one and only call to `__call__`. This new function happens to do the logging-logic, so the logging happens every time you call `myfunc1` now.

Comment: okay, but why doesn't the logging happen without `new_func` when calling `myfunc1` for the second time? **edit**: by the way, i set a breakpoint in `__call__` without `new_func` and the breakpoint was hit only once. how come?

Comment: @user3132457 the answer to both of these question is that `__call__` is called exactly once. When you fire the script up, `myfunc1 = logit().__call__(myfunc1)` is executed. No more calls to `__call__` after that.

Comment: @user3132457 I recently explained how decorators work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678357/how-a-function-in-python-is-getting-called-by-just-typing-the-name-of-function-a/52678695#52678695), maybe you'll find it useful. The crucial point is that the decorator only gets called once for producing a new function.

Comment: i see. so if i defined another `@logit() def myfunc2(): pass`, `__call__` would be called again. and, if first time `myfunc1 = logit().__call__(myfunc1)` executed, what does `myfunc2` equal when i call it again?

Comment: @user3132457 after decoration, `myfunc2` will be a function that first does the logging logic and then execute the old code of `myfunc2` (before decoration) which in your example does nothing (you just `pass`).